# bashscript combine multiple json files into one json

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a folder that contains subfolders of json files inside.

I need to write a bash script that combine all json files into one big valid json.

1) Tried first to use jq to combine first, all json files into each directory and later on I'll need to combine all into one big file again.
I didn't manage to make it work. I used this command:

```
jq -rs 'reduce .[] as $item ({}; . * $item)'
```

2) Other option is to create a json file at the beginning with "[" --> Process all files from all directories and for each file append the content --> append "]" at the end.

Can I achieve the same result with first way using jq only?

Comment: Actually I managed to get rid of the [] by doing : jq '.[]' $jsonFile >> $merged_json

Answer (score 10, accepted):

a very simple way is :

```
jq -s 'flatten' $target/*/*.json > $merged_json
```

a alternative ( in the case you need to use `|` ) :

```
cat $target/*/*.json | jq -s 'flatten' > $merged_json
```

or if too many files

```
find $target/* -name \*json cat {} |  jq -s 'flatten' > $merged_json
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for the target folder. But when I tried to use it inside the loop to create a separate file for each directory it didn't create the file!!! cat $d/*.json | jq -s 'flatten' > "$dir_name"_merged.json   where dir_name=$(basename $d)

Comment: you need to adapt , to your need  .... you dont need to do the second loop

Comment: Please ignore it, my bad. I was creating it in a different location

Comment: Even don't need the `cat` as jq will accept the $STDIN `jq -s 'flatten' $target/*/*.json > $merged_json`